# cakePHP isAuthorized not working

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, controller

I have a table which splits my users (user_levels) linked to the users table (user_level_id). Level 5 is administrator.

I want to limit certain actions from being viewed and understand I can do this with isAuthorized. I went according to book and I am pretty sure I have it right, but it is not working. It allows any logged in users to still access any of the actions although I deny it in isAuthorized.

Here is my code:

```
 App Controller:public $components = array(
    'Session',

    'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login',
        ),
        'authError' => "Your username and password is incorrect, please try again.",
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'scope' => array('User.user_status_id' => 1)
            )
        ),
        'redirect' => array("controller" => "users", "action" => "profile"),
        'loginRedirect' => array("controller" => "users", "action" => "profile")
    )
);

public function isAuthorized($user = null) {
    if($this->Auth->user("user_level_id") == 5) {
        return true;
    }
    // Default deny
    return false;
}

public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow("display");
   if($this->Auth->loggedIn() == true) {
       $this->set("user_name",$this->Auth->user("first_name")." ".$this->Auth->user("last_name"));
       $this->set("loggedIn",true);
       if($this->Auth->user("user_type_id") == 5) {
           $this->set("navigation","navigation_admin");
       } else {
           $this->set("navigation","navigation_loggedin");
       }
   } else {
       $this->set("loggedIn",false);
       $this->set("navigation","navigation_notloggedin");
   }

}

 }

 // Users Controller:

 public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow("login");
    parent::beforeFilter();
}

public function isAuthorized($user = null) {
    if($this->Auth->user("user_level_id") == 5) {

        return true;
    }
    // Default deny
    return parent::isAuthorized($user);
}
```

Comment: which book are you following?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you're just missing the configuration to just tell the AuthComponent to use `isAuthorized()`.

```
'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login',
        ),
        'authError' => "Your username and password is incorrect, please try again.",
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'scope' => array('User.user_status_id' => 1)
            )
        ),
        'authorize' => array('Controller'), // <- here
        'redirect' => array("controller" => "users", "action" => "profile"),
        'loginRedirect' => array("controller" => "users", "action" => "profile")
    )
```

Comment: hey jeremy, thank you for your reply, just 1 question, I still don't quite understand how I block say the standard users from specific actions. As an example, my users controller has a number of actions, and standard users can example access profile and register, but actions like add, edit and delete I would want blocked. How do I do this within the isAuthorized()? I know I cant use allow and deny as that is only applicable to non-logged in users.

Comment: Generally you would use ACL to do something like that. However, you can still do this with a custom `isAuthorized()` in each controller and store an array of allowed actions per user group, then check against that. Either way, that's enough of a topic for a new discussion.

Comment: @jeremyharris One off-topic question; why there are "redirect" and "loginRedirect" options existing and pointing out the same URL?

Comment: @ozanmuyes truthfully I think I just copied/pasted from OP and fixed what wasn't working. I didn't check everything. `redirect` doesn't appear to be needed or even used.